# PyInstaller and Enthought Suite

Tags: python, pyinstaller, enthought, mayavi, pythonxy

I was wondering if anyone has any success in creating a stand alone executable using pyinstaller with a script that has enthought imports.  I have been trying to do this for a couple of days now, however I keep getting an import error.  Through some digging around I believe that I might need to add some hidden import and create my own hooks.  However I have not heard of anyone having any success with this, so I thought I would ask here and see if anyone might have some experience with this situation.

Comment: I have not used PyInstaller, but I have used py2exe to package ETS GUI apps. You will almost certainly need to use `--onedir --hidden-import=traitsui.qt4 --hidden-import=pyface.ui.qt4` (replace `qt4` with `wx` if you are using wxPython).

Comment: Do you think you could provide me with the setup script you used to package ETS with py2exe.  I would like to work with an example if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that was proprietary work for a client.

Comment: If you want to try out py2exe, Thomas Lecocq has a post that walks you through a [simple example](http://www.geophysique.be/2011/08/01/pack-an-enthought-traits-app-inside-a-exe-using-py2exe-ets-4-0-edit/)

Answer (score 0):

I had been trying to build a stand alone exe of my python app which uses matplotlib (one of the components of enthought) and was having lots of trouble getting it to work.  Finally found a bug post (http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/651) on pyinstaller site that told me that it was a bug in pyinstaller.  I followed the reference in that post to download the fixed version of pyinstaller at ​https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/61

Now my build to stand alone exe works fine.  I bet you were experiencing the same problem as me.  see... [Building python pylab/matplotlib exe using pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095180/building-python-pylab-matplotlib-exe-using-pyinstaller)